# Automating create-next-app with heredocs doesn't work, why?

Tags: shell, heredoc

Output from terminal

```bash
> npx create-next-app@latest <<EOF
app1
No
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
@/*
EOF
? What is your project named? › app1NoYesYesYesYesYes@/*%
```

Why this doesn't create a nextjs app?

Here is a normal flow of using create-next-app. Just to let you know the outputs.

```bash
> npx create-next-app@latest
Need to install the following packages:
  create-next-app@13.4.19
Ok to proceed? (y) y
✔ What is your project named? … my-app
✔ Would you like to use TypeScript? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use ESLint? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use `src/` directory? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to customize the default import alias? … No / Yes
✔ What import alias would you like configured? … @/*
Creating a new Next.js app in /Users/zequn/Desktop/t4/my-app.

...
Success! Created my-app at /path/to/project
```

Comment: FYI the command can be used in a non-interactive way as documented here : https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/create-next-app#non-interactive

Comment: What does `npx` expect the data stream to be? Is it just reading `stdin`? Is it a script?, executable? If it reads `stdin` a heredoc is fine, but an `expect` script may also be what you are looking for.